# How realistic is qualifying for so many badges worn by Vicky Kaushal?

Tags: realism, uri-the-surgical-strike

Recently saw the *Uri: The Surgical Strike* trailer starring Vicky Kaushal.

I recognize some badges worn by him. Namely the paratrooper badge and special forces badge. But he is wearing many badges.

[image: Vicky Kaushal in URI.]

How realistic is this depiction ?

Comment: I would like to refer you to the story of Audie Murphy.  He was a US infantryman in WWII who over the course of his life earned 24 different _unique_ medals, awards, and honors from three different countries, not counting multiples of the same award.  He's a rather extreme case, but does show that such levels of decoration are indeed realistically possible.  Wikipedia has a rather good picture of him in full dress uniform on the page about him if you want to see what that many awards looks like.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following is my breakdown of the badges worn by Vicky Kaushal:

[image: Breakdown of badges.]

[image: Service Ribbons]

In the movie, Vicky Kaushal's character is a Major in the Para Special Forces of the Indian army.

An officer takes 9-10 years to go from Lieutenant to Major. And Special Forces is the front line force for dealing with counter-insurgency. They are kept at an optimal efficiency level to deal with such events anytime.

Hence they undergo a lot of training as compared to other branches of the army, which explains the number of badges earned.

Meet the late [Major Mohit Sharma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohit_Sharma_(soldier)). You can see the number of badges he earned.

[**SSBCrack.com**](https://www.ssbcrack.com/2017/10/decoding-the-badges-of-a-para-special-force-commando.html) decodes all these badges perfectly.

So **yes**, the depiction is very realistic.